# Tensorflow siamese CNN model always predicts the same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a siamese CNN model for deepfake detection. The model takes pairs of 3D images. Each pair consists of a 3D face image and a 3D background block image. The 3D image is formed by stacking images across multiple frames where the number of stacked frames is referred to as depth. Each 3D image has the shape `(height, width, depth, channels=3)` and dtype=float32. The images are normalized to have values between 0.0 and 1.0. I use a custom data generator to generate batches of data. The data generator is tested and provides the data as expected. Each generated batch consists of a tuple of `([input1, input2], output)` where each input has shape `(batch_size, img_height, img_width, img_depth, 3)` and each output has shape `(batch_size, 1)` because it's a binary classification problem and the output is either 0 (for real) or 1 (for fake).

The assumption is for real videos, the noise patterns are the same for both the face and the background. However, for fake videos the face is manipulated while the background isn't. So the noise patterns will be different. The objective is to train a siamese network to extract features related to noise patterns from the face and background and calculate a distance score (between 0 and 1). For real videos the distance score should be close to 0. And for fake videos the distance should be close to 1.

My base model is a 3D CNN model with the following architecture:

```
def create_3D_CNN(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    # 1
    model.add(Conv3D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 1), strides=(2, 2, 1), padding='same'))
    # 2
    model.add(Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 3
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 4
    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
    # 5
    model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
    # final
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    return model
```

It extracts 1024 features from each input sample. Because it's a siamese network, there are 2 inputs which are processed in parallel (face and background) by the same 3D CNN using shared weights. Each input is converted to a vector of 1024 features. Assume the two vectors are called `a` and `b`.

The two vectors are fed to an output layer which calculates a distance value score between 0 and 1 based on the Manhattan distance. The equation of the output layer is as follows:

```
predicted_output = 1 - exp(-sum|a_i - b_i|)
```

When `a` and `b` are smilar, the predicted_output will be close to 0. When `a` and `b` are very different, the predicted_output will be close to 1.

Here is the code for the rest of the model:

```
def manhatten_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return 1 - K.exp(-K.sum(K.abs(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))

def man_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)


input_shape = train_gen[0][0][0][0].shape
print('input_shape =', input_shape)

#-------------- defining layers using functional api ----------------------
# inputs
input_face = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_back = Input(shape=input_shape)
# feature extraction (shared weights)
CNN_3D = create_3D_CNN(input_shape)
features_face = CNN_3D(input_face)
features_back = CNN_3D(input_back)
# distance between the 2 feature vectors
distance = Lambda(manhatten_distance, output_shape=man_dist_output_shape)([features_face, features_back])

#---------------- creating final model ---------------------------
model = Model(inputs=[input_face, input_back], outputs=distance)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

However, when I train the model, the accuracy is always close to 50% and the loss (binary_crossentropy) doesn't decrease below 7.8. When I try to make predictions after training I always get the same value.

What could be the reason for this?

---

Update:

To narrow down the issue I think the problem has to do with the Manhattan distance layer.
I replaced it with a "concatenate" layer and added another layer for output with 1 neuron and sigmoid activation and the model seems to be learning.

Why would the Manhattan distance layer prevent the model from learning?

Comment: Can't find any code problem. Did you check the input data and the labels? Can the model overfit on an abusively small dataset (just to check if the model can actually recognize a pattern) with like a couple of examples?

Comment: I tried training the network using 4 videos (2 real videos and 2 fake ones). The accuracy and loss at the end of each epoch are constant for 30 epochs (loss = 7.0482, accuracy = 0.5378)

Comment: I replaced the distance layer with concatenate (instead of calculating the distance between the two vectors I concatenated them together) and added another layer for output with a single unit and sigmoid activation. The model can now easily overfit the small dataset. I think the problem has to do with the Manhattan distance layer.